# What programming languages are normally compiled into non-machine specific code?

Tags: compilation, programming-languages

Any specific reasons would be nice too.

As some people have pointed out; Java is translated into Bytecode, which runs in JVM. Are there any which don't depend on a virtual machine? Historical or contemporary, obsolete or not.

Comment: Did you try anything (this includes research)?

Comment: Is this homework? Any language that runs with an intermediary layer would qualify I think.

Comment: Most languages that run on a virtual machine would fall into this category. Wikipedia has a [big list of examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode).

Comment: I have looked in a programming language concepts book and on the web at various websites on compilation but I can't seem to find an actual comparison of the compilation mechanisms for different languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out, portable ByteCode is platform independent, 
you can find a List of **ByteCode** Languages on eg. [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode).
But they depend on an Interpreter or a Virtual Machine, ie. JVM.
And there is also LLVM, which provides a middle layer in an intermediate form (IF).

Comment: Ok do you know of any languages that are translated into non-machine specific code that don't depend on a virtual machine?

Comment: Then they depend on an (ByteCode, AST or SourceCode) Intepreter, like Emacs LISP.

Comment: You may say VM's are Interpreters, but not vice versa. Could you  specify non-machine specific code?

Comment: Sorry, I got confused with the wording of my question

Comment: I have learnt about interpreters but with the wording of it I thought they were looking for something else, something which doesn't seem to exist :)